# Hyperbolic polyhedron in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to create the following hyperbolic polyhedra in Latex using tikz. I can create the hexagonal structure, but I'm clueless regarding the circular arcs.
[image: Polyhedron]

Edit: The code I used for the hexagonal part is as follows (Kindly rotate it):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{wrwrwr}{rgb}{0.38,0.38,0.38}
\definecolor{rvwvcq}{rgb}{0.082,0.39,0.75}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm]
\fill[line width=2pt,color=rvwvcq,fill=rvwvcq,fill opacity=0.1] (2.08,-2.07) -- (2.1,-0.35) -- (0.6204363054907656,0.5273205080756891) -- (-0.8791273890184694,-0.31535898384862215) -- (-0.8991273890184699,-2.0353589838486217) -- (0.5804363054907642,-2.9126794919243113) -- cycle;
\draw [line width=2pt,color=rvwvcq] (2.08,-2.07)-- (2.1,-0.35);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=rvwvcq] (2.1,-0.35)-- (0.6204363054907656,0.5273205080756891);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=rvwvcq] (0.6204363054907656,0.5273205080756891)-- (-0.8791273890184694,-0.31535898384862215);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=rvwvcq] (-0.8791273890184694,-0.31535898384862215)-- (-0.8991273890184699,-2.0353589838486217);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=rvwvcq] (-0.8991273890184699,-2.0353589838486217)-- (0.5804363054907642,-2.9126794919243113);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=rvwvcq] (0.5804363054907642,-2.9126794919243113)-- (2.08,-2.07);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=wrwrwr] (-0.8791273890184694,-0.31535898384862215)-- (2.08,-2.07);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=wrwrwr] (-0.8991273890184699,-2.0353589838486217)-- (2.1,-0.35);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=wrwrwr] (0.6204363054907656,0.5273205080756891)-- (0.5804363054907642,-2.9126794919243113);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=wrwrwr] (-0.12934554176385193,0.10598076211353347)-- (-0.15934554176385285,-2.4740192378864663);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=wrwrwr] (-0.15934554176385285,-2.4740192378864663)-- (2.09,-1.21);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=wrwrwr] (2.09,-1.21)-- (-0.12934554176385193,0.10598076211353347);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=wrwrwr] (1.3602181527453827,0.08866025403784455)-- (1.330218152745382,-2.4913397459621556);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=wrwrwr] (1.3602181527453827,0.08866025403784455)-- (-0.8891273890184697,-1.1753589838486218);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=wrwrwr] (-0.8891273890184697,-1.1753589838486218)-- (1.330218152745382,-2.4913397459621556);
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw [fill=rvwvcq] (2.08,-2.07) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=rvwvcq] (2.1439168319762962,-1.9047033765096832) node {$A$};
\draw [fill=rvwvcq] (2.1,-0.35) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=rvwvcq] (2.1593385635534776,-0.1851803056539731) node {$B$};
\draw [fill=wrwrwr] (0.6204363054907656,0.5273205080756891) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=wrwrwr] (0.6788523321440775,0.6938583942453586) node {$C$};
\draw [fill=wrwrwr] (-0.8791273890184694,-0.31535898384862215) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=wrwrwr] (-0.8170556308425039,-0.14662597671101996) node {$D$};
\draw [fill=wrwrwr] (-0.8991273890184699,-2.0353589838486217) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=wrwrwr] (-0.8401882282082758,-1.86614904756673) node {$E$};
\draw [fill=wrwrwr] (0.5804363054907642,-2.9126794919243113) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=wrwrwr] (0.6402980032011244,-2.7451877474660615) node {$F$};
\draw [fill=wrwrwr] (-0.8891273890184697,-1.1753589838486218) circle (2pt);
\draw[color=wrwrwr] (-0.8247664966310945,-1.0256646766103514) node {$G$};
\draw [fill=wrwrwr] (-0.12934554176385193,0.10598076211353347) circle (2pt);
\draw[color=wrwrwr] (-0.06910164934921317,0.25433904429569276) node {$H$};
\draw [fill=wrwrwr] (1.3602181527453827,0.08866025403784455) circle (2pt);
\draw[color=wrwrwr] (1.4190954478487776,0.23891731271851147) node {$I$};
\draw [fill=wrwrwr] (2.09,-1.21) circle (2pt);
\draw[color=wrwrwr] (2.151627697764887,-1.056508139764714) node {$J$};
\draw [fill=wrwrwr] (1.330218152745382,-2.4913397459621556) circle (2pt);
\draw[color=wrwrwr] (1.3882519846944152,-2.344222726459349) node {$K$};
\draw [fill=wrwrwr] (-0.15934554176385285,-2.4740192378864663) circle (2pt);
\draw[color=wrwrwr] (-0.09994511250357566,-2.321090129093577) node {$L$};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It would be nice if you showed the code to create the hexagonal thing then people can just complete the drawing with the arcs instead of drawing everything from scratch.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, I added the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A dirty solution using `shapes` library.

```
\documentclass[margin=3.1415mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1mm]
\node (A) [draw,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, minimum size=10cm,outer sep=0pt] {};
\draw ($(A.corner 2)!0.5!(A.corner 3)$)coordinate(2-3)--($(A.corner 4)!0.5!(A.corner 5)$)coordinate(4-5);
\draw ($(A.corner 1)!0.5!(A.corner 2)$)coordinate(1-2)--($(A.corner 5)!0.5!(A.corner 6)$)coordinate(5-6);
\draw (4-5)--($(A.corner 6)!0.5!(A.corner 1)$)coordinate(6-1);
\draw ($(A.corner 3)!0.5!(A.corner 4)$)coordinate(3-4)--(1-2);
\draw (A.corner 2)--(A.corner 5);
\draw (A.corner 1)--(A.corner 4);
\draw (A.corner 3)--(A.corner 6);
\draw (2-3)--(6-1);
\draw (3-4)--(5-6);
\node at (90:6.5)[draw,circle,minimum size=1pt](circ){};
\draw (1-2)--(circ.270);
\draw [] (A.corner 2) to [bend left=45] (circ.180);
\draw [] (A.corner 1) to [bend right=45] (circ.0);
\draw [] (2-3) to [bend left=45] (circ.170);
\draw [] (6-1) to [bend right=45] (circ.10);
\draw [] (A.corner 3) to [bend left=45] (circ.165);
\draw [] (A.corner 6) to [bend right=45] (circ.15);
\draw (3-4) to [out=170,in=-100] ($(2-3)+(-2,0)$) to [out=80,in=180] (circ.160);
\draw (5-6) to [out=10,in=-80] ($(6-1)+(2,0)$) to [out=100,in=0] (circ.20);
\draw (A.corner 4) to [out=170,in=-80] ($(A.corner 3)+(-2.5,0)$) to [out=100,in=180] (circ.160);
\draw (A.corner 5) to [out=10,in=-100] ($(A.corner 6)+(2.5,0)$) to [out=80,in=0] (circ.20);
\draw (4-5) to [out=-80,in=195] ($(A.corner 6)+(0,-5.5)$) to [out=20,in=-90] ($(A.corner 6)+(4,0)$)to [out=90,in=0](circ.20);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. It is almost as I wanted it. However, is there any way that you could "smoothen" it?

Comment: What do you mean by "smoothen"?

Comment: @user473334 If you like an answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](//tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and marking it as [accepted answer](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Comment: @ferahfeza Can we change the curvature of the arcs to make them more circular?

Comment: @Andrew I can't upvote because my reputation is low.

Comment: @user473334, you can play with the `in` and `out` values of arcs. In addition, you have to define more points on the arc routes.