# The following mesh/grid like diagram in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to create a picture as shown in the attachment. I know how to create the hexagonal substructure and the code for the same can be found in this question: [Hyperbolic polyhedron in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/485019/173540)

Please help me out as I'm new to tikz.

[image]

Edit: The function which maps the subdivided icosahedron to the plane behaves like $z^{6/5}$ at the vertex of degree 5 (hereby denoted by $v$).

Comment: Show us the origin of the picture. We might be able to find useful parametrization therein.

Comment: Basically, I am subdividing an icosahedron and mapping it using a conformal map (except at the 12 vertices of degree 5) to the plane. So in this image, there is one vertex of degree 5 and the others are of degree 6.

Comment: You might use nonlinear transformations to achieve this but should not expect us to extract the conformal map from the picture.

Comment: The conformal map is not described explicitly. Its behavior is known (it distorts the triangles near the vertex of degree 5 and as we move further the triangles are nearly equilateral). What kind of nonlinear transformations should I use? Could you please elaborate, @marmot?

Comment: A Ti*K*z based package `luamesh` can be help you: https://ctan.org/pkg/luamesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw such grids with `\foreach` loops.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[web/.style={append after command={foreach \XX in {1,...,#1} 
 {(current.corner \XX)
 -- (current.center)}},regular polygon,regular polygon sides=#1,minimum
  size=1cm,draw,alias=current},
  pics/outerior/.style={code={
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\idiv}{pow(2,#1-1)}
  \draw (90:#1*0.5) foreach \XX in {1,...,5}
   {-- (90+72*\XX:#1*0.5) coordinate (P-\XX)};
  \draw (90:#1*0.5+0.5) foreach \XX in {1,...,5}
   {-- coordinate[midway] (M-\XX) (90+72*\XX:#1*0.5+0.5) coordinate (Q-\XX)}; 
  \foreach \XX [remember=\XX as \YY (initially 5)] in {1,...,5} 
  {\draw (P-\XX) -- (Q-\XX);
  \foreach \ZZ in {0,...,#1}
   {\draw ($(Q-\XX)!{(\ZZ+1)/(#1+1)}!(Q-\YY)$) -- ($(P-\XX)!{\ZZ/#1}!(P-\YY)$) --
   ($(Q-\XX)!{\ZZ/(#1+1)}!(Q-\YY)$) ;}
  }
  }}]
 \draw (0,0) node[web=5] (c5) {};
 \clip (-3,-3) rectangle (3,3);
 \draw foreach \X in {1,...,9} {(0,0) pic{outerior=\X}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

P.S. Your prescription does not seem to yield the drawn lattice when using regular polygons (and also to introduce polygons that automatically have the internal lines added via `append after command`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[web/.style={append after command={foreach \XX in {1,...,#1} 
 {(current.corner \XX)
 -- (current.center)}},regular polygon,regular polygon sides=#1,minimum
  size=1cm,draw,alias=current}]
 \draw (0,0) node[web=5] (c5) {};
 \foreach \X [remember=\X as \Y (initially 5)] in {1,...,5}
 {\draw 
 let \p1=($(c5.corner \Y)-(c5.corner \X)$),\n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)} 
 in ($(c5.corner \Y)!0.5!(c5.corner \X)$) coordinate (aux) 
    ($(aux)!{-(1/2)*1cm}!90:(c5.corner \X)$) 
    node[web=6,minimum size=6cm/5,rotate=\n1]{};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just a comment: OP's picture seems to be an unstructured mesh, generated by some meshing algorithm. These algorithms mostly work from the outlines of the domain towards the middle, so some geometry (which is not shown in the picture) caused the algorithm to converge to a pentagon in that spot. But generally no triangles are equilateral in these meshes, so I think OP's request is rather unpractical :/

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Yes. I still think one can use nonlinear transformations to get that grid but not the OP's prescription.

Comment: @marmot The picture that you generated is "very nice" (in the sense that it has only linear components). The problem is that I need the triangles near the vertex of degree 5 to be small and distorted whereas as we go further they should be nearly equilateral. Can this effect be created?

Answer (score 1):

This mesh structure is generated with Delaunay triangulation method. You know that this method is quite complicated. The `luamesh` package wrote by [Maxime Chupin](https://www.ceremade.dauphine.fr/~chupin/?lang=en) is a great work for using Delaunay triangulation in TeX/LaTeX.

The Ti*K*z based package `luamesh` can be downloaded from [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/luamesh). In the web site page, click download link as seen following picture.
[image]

Extract the zip file in a directory. You will see a directory named `scripts`. The files in this directory are required `lua` scripts for the package. Write a code like following and save it in `scripts` directory.

```
\documentclass[margin=3.1415mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamesh}

\begin{document}

  \meshPolygon[
  tikz,
  color = blue!70,
  %meshpoint = \alpha,
  colorPolygon=black,
  scale=4cm,
  step=mesh,
 % print=points,
  gridpoints=perturb
  ]
  {(0,0);(1,0);(1,1);(0,1)}

\end{document}
```

Now compile this file with `LuaLaTeX`. The result is as follows.
[image]

**ADDENDUM:**
You can adjust the mesh density with `h` value. The mesh parameter, it is the unit distance for the grid. If necessary, the boundary is refined to get points which respect the distance constrain. Default value is 0.2. Add the `h` parameter to `\meshPolygon` environment, like:

```
\meshPolygon[
  tikz,
  color = blue!70,
  %meshpoint = \alpha,
  colorPolygon=black,
  scale=4cm,
  step=mesh,
 % print=points,
  gridpoints=perturb,
  h=0.1
  ]
  {(0,0);(1,0);(1,1);(0,1)}
```

An the result:
[image]

Comment: `luamesh` is in both TeX Live and MikTeX.  There should be virtually no need to download manually.

Comment: @HenriMenke, you are right. But the contributors say in `luamesh-doc.pdf` at page 4, "As these two systems are unknown to the contributor, we refer to the documentation for integrating local additions to MikTEX:
http://docs.miktex.org/manual/localadditions.html". This is for the how to using the `.lua` files. I pointed out a simple way.

Comment: Besides, I didn't say to install the package.

Comment: I pasted your example and typeset successfully with LuaLaTeX without having to download and extract anything.  It might be unnecessary.